# Trouble with Ajax/json and spring mvc

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, json

--edit--
What is happening is I can see with console/sout items that I am getting the object from the DB, and currentyly I am getting a 500 internal server error, every fix I have tried one error goes away (400 has been very popular) and then I get another, i fix it then I get another.

I am getting the data, but it the call keeps failing and I can't do anything with the information, I am seeing that data, but I can't figure out how to catch it properly.

What I am trying to do is search for a customer, if that customer exists populate that information in the next page form, if not just insert the search criteria into the corresponding fields in the next page form.

Here is javascript, I can't figure out the load function because it doesn't seem to work right (not sure how to catch the data correctly it seems).

```
$('#search-customer').click(function (event) {
        var testdata = document.getElementById('searchCustomerForm');
        // var isvalid = checkForm(form);
//        if (isvalid === false) {
//            event.preventDefault();
//            alert('is valid===false');
//        } else {
        alert('hit search customer ajaxcall');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'customerLookup/?firstName=' + $('#search_first_Name').val() + '&lastName=' + $('#search_last_Name').val() + '&compId=' + companyId,
            data: JSON.stringify({
                firstName: $('#search-first_name').val(),
                lastName: $('#search-last_name').val(),
                //  dob: $('#search_birthdate').val(),
                // license: $('#search_license_number').val()
                //  dob: $('#search_birthdate').val(),
                compId: $('#search_companyId').val(companyId)
            }),
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            'dataType': 'json'
        }).done(function (data, status) {
            if (data !== null) {
                window.location = "/app/ticketStepOneTwoAddCustomer";
                loadCustomerInputForm(data, status);
                alert('customer found, moving to confirm');
            }
            else if (data === null) {
                window.location = "/app/ticketStepOneTwoAddCustomer";
                addSearchInfoToInputCustomerForm();
                alert('no customer of that name found, moving to add customer');
            }
        }).fail(function () {
            alert('not a success');
          //  window.location = "/app/ticketStepOneTwoAddCustomer";
        });
    });


function loadinputcustomerform(data, status) {
    alert('hit loadinputcustomerform function');
    console.log(cust.customer.getCustomerFirstName());
    console.log(data.customer.getCustomerMiddleName());
    console.log(customer.getCustomerLastName());
```

Here is the Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/customerLookup"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Customer getCustomerByCriteria(
            @RequestParam(value = "compId", required = false) int compId,
            @RequestParam(value = "firstName", required = false) String fName,
            @RequestParam(value = "lastName", required = false) String lName) {
        System.out.println("here: " + compId + " -- " + fName);
        Customer cust = customerService.searchCustomer(fName, lName, compId);
        //System.out.println(cust.getCustomerLicense());
      return cust;
    }
```

On the java side the customer is just an object, in the DB the companyID is the FK, everything requires the compID, I was thinking They should have made a customer hashmap or list but not my area and it is what I have to work with.

here is the html

```
<form id="inputCustomerForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_first_Name" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" placeholder="First Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="middleName">Middle Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_middle_Name" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"  placeholder="Middle Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="input_last_Name" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" placeholder="Last Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="dob">D.O.B. YYYYMMDD</label>
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="input_birthdate" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" placeholder="YYYYMMDD">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="addressone">Address</label>
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="input_addressone" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" placeholder="123 street">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="addresstwo">Address</label>
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="input_addresstwo" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" placeholder="po 1111">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="city">City</label>
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="input_city" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" placeholder="Columbus">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="state">State</label>
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="input_state" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" placeholder="OH">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="zip">ZipCode</label>
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="input_zip" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" placeholder="43026">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="licenseNumber">License Number</label>
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="input_license_number" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" placeholder="License Number">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="licenseInputFile">File input</label>
                        <input type="file" id="licensePhoto">
                        <p class="help-block">License Photo</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="customerPhotoInputFile">File input</label>
                        <input type="file" id="customerPhoto">
                        <p class="help-block">Customer Photo</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="input-customer" class="btn btn-default" >Submit</button>
                      </form>
```

here is the response

```
HTTP Status 500 - Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: com.REMOVED.DTO.Customer["company"]->com.REMOVED.DTO.Company_$$_jvstf68_6["handler"]); nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: com.REMOVED.DTO.Customer["company"]->com.REMOVED.DTO.Company_$$_jvstf68_6["handler"])

type Exception report

message Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: com.REMOVED.DTO.Customer["company"]->com.REMOVED.DTO.Company_$$_jvstf68_6["handler"]); nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: com.REMOVED.DTO.Customer["company"]->com.REMOVED.DTO.Company_$$_jvstf68_6["handler"])

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: com.REMOVED.DTO.Customer["company"]->com.REMOVED.DTO.Company_$$_jvstf68_6["handler"]); nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: com.REMOVED.DTO.Customer["company"]->com.REMOVED.DTO.Company_$$_jvstf68_6["handler"])
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:212)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:207)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:148)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:90)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:193)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
root cause

org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: com.REMOVED.DTO.Customer["company"]->com.REMOVED.DTO.Company_$$_jvstf68_6["handler"])
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:52)
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:25)
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:610)
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:256)
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1613)
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:209)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:207)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:148)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:90)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:193)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.15 logs.
```

I was thinking that the customer properties being private was an issue but with public getters and setters i thought it would still work.

Comment: Need more information.  What do you mean by "not working"?  What results are you getting from your AJAX call if you look at your browser's javascript debugger?  Is your Java method in the controller executing successfully?  What is it returning?  What error messages are you getting?

Comment: I added a little more information, the controller is executing and I am getting the sout that I put in there to confirm, however the .done in the search customer ajax call and any part of the load customer function are both failing, I guess how should I catch the data in the loadcustomer? and what might be some of the problems causing my .fail to hit instead of my .done?

Comment: You need to press F12 in your browser to bring up the javascript console and debut that, it will tell you what the server actually sends back for the AJAX request.

Comment: one thing to note is that one error that comes up depending on how I have the code is that it is missing a serialize, which is strange because I thought spring would handle that... and it does... but here it does not

Comment: That's not useful information.  What is the stack trace or error message, exactly?  What is the response from the server to your browser (you'll find that with the browser debugger).  If you don't post specifics, there's no way to help.